# Under which conditions is renaming a file an atomic operation on Linux?

Tags: c++, c, linux, filesystems, rename

### Assumption

According to the [documentation](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/rename.2.html), calling rename on Linux performs an atomic replace:

> If newpath already exists, it will be atomically replaced, so that there is no point at which another process attempting to access newpath will find it missing.

### Contradiction

However, if I run a simple parallel test, with each thread running the following operations:

1. create a file `foo<thread_id>`
2. rename `foo<thread_id>` to `cache_file` (`cache_file` is the same for every thread)
3. hard link `cache_file` to `bar<thread_id>`

it will eventually fail to create the hard link with the following error:
`filesystem error: cannot create hard link: No such file or directory [/app/cache_file] [/app/bar1]`. So it seems that the replacement of `cache_file` is not atomic, as concurrently creating a hard link causes an error. (Note that `cache_file` is actually stored in a content addressable storage, so the overwrite shouldn't do any harm, as the content of the replaced file and the replacement file is exactly the same.)

### Question

Shouldn't the hard link creation always succeed if the replacement operation is atomic, so that the created hard link refers to either the replaced file or the replacement file?

See the minimal working example on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/e483P879b) or here:

```
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <filesystem>
#include <cstdio>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

auto myrename(std::filesystem::path const& from,
              std::filesystem::path const& to, int variant) -> bool {
  switch (variant) {
    case 0: // c++ rename
      std::filesystem::rename(from, to);
      return true;
    case 1: // c rename
      return std::rename(from.c_str(), to.c_str()) == 0;
    case 2: // linux rename (same as std::rename?)
      return rename(from.c_str(), to.c_str()) == 0;
    case 3: // linux link and unlink (no overwrite)
      return (link(from.c_str(), to.c_str()) == 0 or errno == EEXIST)
             and unlink(from.c_str()) == 0;
    case 4: // linux renameat2 without overwrite
      return renameat2(0, from.c_str(), 0, to.c_str(), RENAME_NOREPLACE) == 0
             or (errno == EEXIST and unlink(from.c_str()) == 0);
    default:
      return false;
  }
}

auto mylink(std::filesystem::path const& from, std::filesystem::path const& to,
            int variant) -> bool {
  if (std::filesystem::exists(to)) std::filesystem::remove(to);
  switch (variant) {
    case 0: // c++ hard link
      std::filesystem::create_hard_link(from, to);
      return true;
    case 1: // linux link
      return link(from.c_str(), to.c_str()) == 0;
    default:
      return false;
  }
}

auto create_store_stage(std::string const& id) noexcept -> bool {
  try {
    auto cwd = std::filesystem::current_path();
    auto cache = cwd / "cache_file"; // common
    auto ifile = cwd / ("foo" + id); // thread local
    auto ofile = cwd / ("bar" + id); // thread local
    return std::ofstream{ifile}.put('x') // 1. create input file
           and myrename(ifile, cache, 0) // 2. store in cache
           and mylink(cache, ofile, 0);  // 3. hard link to output file
  } catch (std::exception const& e) {
    std::cout << "caught exception: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    return false;
  }
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
  bool fail{};
  std::vector<std::thread> threads{};
  for (int i{}; i < std::thread::hardware_concurrency(); ++i) {
    threads.emplace_back([id = std::to_string(i), &fail]{
        while (not fail and create_store_stage(id)) {}
        if (errno) perror(("thread " + id + " failed with error").c_str());
        fail = true;
    });
  }
  std::for_each(threads.begin(), threads.end(), [](auto& t) { t.join(); });
  return 0;
}
```

### Additional Notes

- tested on Debian 11 (Kernel 5.10.0) and Ubuntu 20.04 (Kernel 5.8.0)
- tested with GCC 9.3/10.2 and Clang 10.0.0/11.0.0 (although I don't expect the compiler to be the issue)
- `myrename()` variants `3` and `4` work correctly (both do not overwrite, which is fine for a content addressable storage)
- as expected, neither variant `0` nor `1` of `mylink()` does make any difference (both use `link()`, according to strace)
- **interesting:** on WSL2 with Ubuntu 20.04 (Kernel 4.4.0) the `myrename()` variants `0`, `1`, and `2` work correctly, but `3` and `4` fail with `filesystem error: cannot create hard link: Invalid argument [/app/cache_file] [/app/bar3]` and `Invalid argument`, respectively

### *Update

- as pointed out by the busybee, `link()` should be atomic as well. The Linux man pages do not mention any atomic properties, while the [POSIX specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/link.html) explicitly does:

> The link() function shall atomically create a new link for the existing file and the link count of the file shall be incremented by one.

- as mentioned by numzero, this could be an unintended side-effect. But I did some testing and this behavior dates back to at least Kernel version 2.6.32.

Comment: Should `link()` be atomar as well to avoid a race condition?

Comment: @thebusybee This is indeed a very important question. I cannot find any details on this. Does it need to be atomic? I would expect `link()` to create a handle, preventing the file from being deleted in the process. If creating the handle would be atomic, `link()` itself does not need to be atomic?

Comment: Are you testing that on *real* Linux or WSL?

Comment: Tested myself. `open` in place of `link` never fails. So it is interaction of `rename` and `link` that doesn’t work.

Comment: @numzero thanks for pointing that out, I'll try to dig deeper into the interaction of `rename`  and `link`.  (and yes, I was testing on real Linux and additionally on WSL2)

Comment: It might be an unintended side-effect of kernel hardening that takes place around symlinks and hardlinks nowadays. Testing on something ancient like 3.2 or even 2.6 could reveal that.

Comment: @numzero I did some testing and went back until 2.6.32, but same results. I get the feeling that this is intended behavior, as the POSIX specification explicitly mentions "atomically" for `link(2)` while the Linux man page does not...